# Twilio response call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

working on Twilio API on EC2 ubuntu server to respond incoming calls with a simple text message. the script seems to be running good at port #5000, configured port number at security groups too. The response is supposed to show at http://public-dns:5000 but it is not showing up ? any ideas how to fix this ? thoughts ?

Comment: Does Twillio hit your script, what Wireshark says?

Comment: Use a browser and hit your url, what do you see?

Comment: Also what do you see in the logs of that incoming call when you go to Twilio Console  ?

Comment: What is the error message you get?